# CSS Grid template areas in wrong order

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying to position the 'nav' div below the 'map' div when the screen size is below 800px. I use grid-template-areas to position the elements, however when the screen shrinks the template areas are in the wrong order.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  /* grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr)); */
  grid-template-columns: 300px 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "nav map"
}

.a {
  grid-column: nav;
}

.b {
  grid-column: map;
  background: blue;
}

.box {
  border: black 1px solid;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .wrapper {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 300px 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "map" "nav"
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box a">nav</div>
  <div class="box b">map</div>
</div>
```

FIDDLE:
https://jsfiddle.net/fmkb4jav/45/

Comment: `grid-template-areas` should be space separated not by quotations

Comment: I have changed but result is even further from intended.

Comment: @AliSheikhpour his grid-template-area was correct

Comment: typo issue : `grid-column` --> `grid-area` (voting to close as typo)

Comment: I was actually correct, grid-template-areas was supposed to be seperated by quotations.

Comment: don't add the solution inside the question. Better delete it because it will get closed and deleted later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your have specified `grid-column` instead of `grid-area` in your classes.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  /* grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr)); */
  grid-template-columns: 300px 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "nav map"
}

.a {
  grid-area: nav;
}

.b {
  grid-area: map;
  background: blue;
}

.box {
  border: black 1px solid;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .wrapper {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 300px 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "map" "nav"
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box a">nav</div>
  <div class="box b">map</div>
</div>
```